# Keras/Tensorflow predict: error in array shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, reshape, keras

I'm following the [Keras CIFAR10 tutorial here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py).
The only changes I made were:

[a] added to the end of tutorial file

```
model.save_weights('./weights.h5', overwrite=True)
```

[b] changed ~./keras/keras.json to

```
{"floatx": "float32", "backend": "tensorflow", "epsilon": 1e-07}
```

I can run the model successfully.

Then I want to test a single image against the trained model. My code:

```
[... similar to tutorial file with model being created and compiled...]
...
model = Sequential()
...
model.compile()

model.load_weights('./ddx_weights.h5')

img = cv2.imread('car.jpeg', -1) # this is is a 32x32 RGB image
img = np.array(img)
y_pred = model.predict_classes(img, 1)
print(y_pred)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 32, 3) for Tensor 'convolution2d_input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3, 32, 32)'
```

What is the correct way of reshaping the input data for a single image to be tested?

I have **not** added `"image_dim_ordering": "tf"` in `./keras/keras.json`.

Comment: care to explain the down vote? that would help for future posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reshape the input image to have a shape of `[?, 3, 32, 32]` where `?` is the batch size. In your case, since you have 1 image the batch size is 1, so you can do:

```py
img = np.array(img)
img = img.reshape((1, 3, 32, 32))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the cifar10 data now, I found that a simple reshape will not work, should use numpy.transpose instead.